# NPM error install angular 2 CLI : tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=405

Tags: node.js, angular

When i installed angular 2 cli I get an error with the NPM :

```
Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-48_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-48_binding.node":

tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=405

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.
export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via
npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

node -v : 6.9.4, 
 npm -v :3.10.10

I don't use proxy. I have done few things like :

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean
npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

but not working, I also have searched stackoverflow for few days, I don't get a solution, thank you..

Answer (score 0):

HI I was facing the same issue and i did following configuration change.
Execute following commands in command prompt.

**npm config set proxy null**

**npm config set https-proxy null**

Hope it help you as well.